# ReferenceError: $nuxt is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js

I've developed a frontend using nuxt, currently no ssr + nuxt auth.
On my localhost in development mode everything works fine.
On production when I log in and being redirected from `/` to a `/forum` page everything also works fine, but when I refresh a page (using Ctrl + R) I get `ReferenceError: $nuxt is not defined`, and the page is not loading. Then when I go to a '/' page manually in a browser everything starts to work normally again.

This issue does not happen on `/login` and `/signup` pictures. I thought it might be caused by nuxt-auth, but when I deleted `middleware: 'auth'` from the code of `/forum`, the issue did not disappear.

EDIT:
If I want to access a page other than `/login` and `/signup` using a direct link, the issue occurs.

Example of a link, that doesn't work:
http://edu-terra-client-env.eba-n9cpbu3q.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ourstory
But you can access it by clicking `Read more` on the bottom of a landing page (see the link below)

This is a page which has almost only plain html+css, so I'm not sure that sharing the code will help.

Examples of a link that works:
http://edu-terra-client-env.eba-n9cpbu3q.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/landing

Also I've noted a moment relevant to the issue: I had the same problem with links in a `<b-list-group-item :href=...>` tag. After I changed :href to :to, links began working fine. Example:

```html
<b-list-group-item v-for="post in postList" :href="'/forum/category/post/'+ post.id" :key="post.id" class="posts-row">
       {{post.title}} 
</b-list-group-item>
```

During building, nuxt uses a `static` mode, while I set  `target: 'server'` in a nuxt.config.

[This is a screenshot of a building process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/259Wt.png)

My nuxt config file is below:

````js
export default {
    target: 'server',
    
    // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
    ssr: false,

    // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
    head: {
        title: 'edu-terra',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'en'
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
        ]
    },

    // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
    css: [
        '@/assets/scss/customTheme.scss'
    ],

    // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
    plugins: [
        '~/plugins/vue-clamp.js',
        '~/plugins/vue-carousel.js',
        '~/plugins/vue-chats.js',
        "~/plugins/vee-validate.js",
        '~/plugins/persistedState.client.js',
        "~/plugins/vue-upload-drop-images.js", 
    ],

    // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    buildModules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
        '@nuxtjs/moment'
    ],

    // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    modules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
        ['nuxt-mq'],
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/proxy',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources'        
    ],
    styleResources: {
        scss: [
            '@/assets/scss/*.scss',
        ]
    },
    // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
    axios: {
        proxy: true,
        prefix: '/api',
    },
    proxy: {
        '/api/': { 
            target: process.env.API_URL, 
            pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} 
        }
    },
    moment: {
        timezone: false
    },
    auth: {
        strategies: {
          local: {
            token: {
              property: 'token',
              global: true,
              maxAge: 1800000,
              //required: false,
              // required: true,
              // type: 'Bearer'
            },
            user: {
              property: 'user',
              // autoFetch: true
            },
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
              logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
              user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get'}
            }
          }
        }
    },

    bootstrapVue: {
        // Install the `IconsPlugin` plugin (in addition to `BootstrapVue` plugin)
        icons: true,
        bootstrapCSS: false,
        bootstrapVueCSS: false
    },

    'mq': {
        defaultBreakpoint: 'sm',
        breakpoints: {
          sm: 768,
          md: 1250,
          lg: Infinity,
        }
    },
    
    // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
    build: {
        transpile: ['vue-clamp', 'resize-detector','vue-slick-carousel', 'vue-accordion', 'vee-validate/dist/rules'],
    },
}```
````

Comment: Hi, can you share the code of the page with the `$nuxt` error? Also, can you host it on app.netlify.com/drop or try it locally (build and start) ? What's the value of `target` in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment :-) I added some edits to the post. I'm not sure what code would be helpful since almost all pages work inappropriately. Target option is set to 'server'

Comment: I tried building the project locally and received the same error in production mode on a localhost, also I found that during building nuxt doesn't see the target option that I set in nuxt config ```target: 'server',``` and uses static mode

Comment: What do you mean? What are the commands you're running?

Comment: Error occurs when I start building using `nuxt build`

Comment: Oops, sorry for confusing you. This 'target' relates to proxy middleware. I added a screenshot to the post. I've set a valid API_URL to build and start scripts, and this error has gone, but it has'nt helped

Comment: What the point of building a SPA only (`ssr: false`) but using `target: 'server'`? You should use `target: 'client'` here and `npm run generate` then host it on Netlify or Vercel. Also yeah, since you're in an SPA context (you're basically using Vue), you CAN'T use `href` but need to use `nuxt-link` with a `to` prop.

Comment: The reason for using `target: 'server'` is nuxt-auth middleware, which doesn't work in a static mode. Also when setting `target: 'client'`, I get an error: `Unknown target: client. Falling back to server` on nuxt start

Comment: Oops sorry `target: 'static'`. Nuxt Auth works with a static build AFAIK.

Comment: The good news is that nuxt-auth is working :-) The bad news is that the issue still exists + proxy middleware is not working, and client sends requests to `localhost:3000/api/` (as far as I know, it could be fixed by placing a `/dist` folder to a server and writing some proxy code on a server side)

Comment: The initial issue was about `$nuxt`. Let's maybe fix this one first. Also why do you have a proxy?

Comment: Unfortunately, fixing this proxy issue will not help with `$nuxt` issue, since I still cannot access the page using direct URL, while the `proxy` issue correlates to a connection with a backend. So I would greatly appreciate if we continue diving into the $nuxt issue. I can share the source code, guess that will help

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote above yeah. Also, a question on StackOverflow should be focused around one issue.

Comment: I've created a repository with the code here: https://github.com/pshepelenko/edu-terra

Comment: Your issue is coming from `$nuxt.context.from.path` in `MobileSectionHeader.vue` (error in your browser console). ESlint clearly tells you that `$nuxt` is undefined.